# code not printing when trying to find numbers that are both star and triangular numbers

Tags: java

Im trying to write the code for a program that prints values that are both star and triangle numbers. Although the code just doesnt seem to work and wont print out any values, the function for the starNumbers is working fine although i think that the function for the triangle number is a bit iffy, im not really sure where the problem is.

All help would be greatly appreciated 
thanks

```
public class TriangularNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;
        int i = 1;
        int star = starNumbers(n);
        int triangle = triangleNumbers(i, n);

        while (star > 0)
        {   
            while (star < triangle)
            {
                n++;
                star = starNumbers(n);
            }
            while (triangle < star)
            {
                triangle = triangleNumbers(i, n);
            }
            if (star==triangle)
            {
                System.out.println(star);
            }
        }
    }
    private static int starNumbers (int n) {
        int s = ((6*n)*(n-1)+1);
        return s;
    }
    private static int triangleNumbers( int i, int n){
        int star = starNumbers(n);
        int t = 0;
        while (t<=star)
        {
            t = t + i;
            i++;
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having deja vu... did you copy, paste, and delete your old question (which was closed)?

Comment: yes, i still have a persisting problem, and this is an altered code to the one in the previous question, ive tried to change/build on the code but it still isnt printing any numbers, not even 1... I tried to ask for help on the other one but no one would reply,(it probably being that the question was closed as you stated?)

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: 5 numbers, i believe they are supposed to be 1, 253, 49141, 9533161 and  1849384153

Comment: ive fixed the code so it is printing out values, although its an endless loop of 1's, although ive discovered why this probem persists, its to do with the condition for the while loop in the triangleNumbers function, ill try and find a fix, but will keep updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//try this

public class TriangularNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;
        int i = 1;
        int star = starNumbers(n);
        int triangle = 0;

        while (star > 0){
            star = starNumbers(n++);
            triangle=0;
            //System.out.println("Star "+star);
            while(triangle < star){

                triangle = triangleNumbers(i,star);

                if(star == triangle){
                    System.out.println("match at "+star);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int starNumbers (int n) {
        int s = ((6*n)*(n-1)+1);
        return s;
    }

    private static int triangleNumbers( int i, int star){
        int t = 0;
        while (t<star){
            t = i*(i+1)/2; //get next triangle
            i++;
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man that works perfect, although theres another value thats a match but dont worry ill figure that one out by myself

Comment: ah fixed it, we had to use the formula t = 1 + 2 + 3 + ...(n-1) + n, which is essentially t =+ i; thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is an empty loop:

```
while (star > 0);
```

Should be

```
while(star > 0)
```

However, I see that `if(star==traingle)` condition is never true, so no output is seen.

Comment: thanks, i noticed that problem and have fixed it in the text, however i  dont see why that condition isnt being met? not even for 1? I cant seem to see the problem in the code, I have my suspicions its to do with the triangleNumbers function, but im unsure of what exactly

Comment: Hi, I understand the method starNumbers(int n), given a number it returns nth number in the sequence, how is traingleNumbers suppose to work?

Comment: thats my iffy spot too, essentially what i tried to do was to make it so that once a starNumber was calculated the triangleNumbers function would try to generate a value that equalled that starNumber, if there was one that did(nt), or if the triangleNumber went higher than the starNumber the function would stop, if the starNumber was equal to the triangleNumber they would output, then the next starNumber would be calculated and the procedure would repeat, although im not sure if that works properly according to the code ive wirtten

Comment: From your explanation I posted another solution see if that works :)